# django-rest-auth : email verification failed, giving error

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

**ImproperlyConfigured**

**URL:** `/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/[key]`

`TemplateResponseMixin` requires either a definition of `template_name` or an implementation of `get_template_names()`

I am new to **Django**.

Comment: Can you post the whole error traceback please?

Comment: this is a duplicate post follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658373/email-confirm-error-rest-auth

Answer (score 2):

Paste this code as the last line un urls.py It will handle all verification urls

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Comment: Try adding some more detail, as to why, for someone new to Django

Comment: @DevWaweru please about your solution, it turned it into a template view, how can you solve this if you want it to remain a rest api