# Email confirm error rest-auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I use a standard form for the confirmation email:
from allauth.account.views import confirm_email as allauthemailconfirmation

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$', allauthemailconfirmation, name="account_confirm_email"),    
    url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),

]
```

Settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION='mandatory'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET=False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = False
```

I correctly get an e-mail, but when you try to link:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/MTU:1bn1OD:dQ_mCYi6Zpr8h2aKS9J9BvNdDjA/
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

Comment: 'w+' is not picking up ":" and so it falls back to dra view, please change the regex into the new format

Comment: Change to account-confirm-email/:(\w+):(?P<key>\w+)/$', - not helped

Comment: as the error says, you have to specify `template_name` inside the view, I imagine?

Comment: I use default template from rest-auth

Comment: can you post your view code, and urls.py?

Comment: I use this import "from allauth.account.views import confirm_email as allauthemailconfirmation"

Comment: anyway, can this https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/20 help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found your problem.

This url:

```
/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/MTU:1bn1OD:dQ_mCYi6Zpr8h2aKS9J9BvNdDjA/
```

is not matched by this pattern:

```
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$', allauthemailconfirmation, name="account_confirm_email"),
```

but by the following:

```
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
```

and if you look at the source code of `rest_auth.registration.urls`, you will see this code:

```
# This url is used by django-allauth and empty TemplateView is
# defined just to allow reverse() call inside app, for example when email
# with verification link is being sent, then it's required to render email
# content.

# account_confirm_email - You should override this view to handle it in
# your API client somehow and then, send post to /verify-email/ endpoint
# with proper key.
# If you don't want to use API on that step, then just use ConfirmEmailView
# view from:
# django-allauth https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L190
url(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
```

So, you should overwrite this view, or you will get the error you've got, as explained here: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/20

You have indeed tried to overwrite the view, but your matching pattern is wrong, the : char causes it to fail, so let's try something like

```
url(r'^rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', allauthemailconfirmation, name="account_confirm_email"),
```

The relevant part being: **(?P[-:\w]+)/$**